# how to make Visual Studios 2012 add a "}" right after a type a "{"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

would just like to know if it is possible to have Visual Studios add a closing "}" right after I type the opening "{".  So right after I type:

```
private void someMethod() {
```

I would like it to go ahead and do something like this:

```
private void someMethod() { }
```

or...

```
private void someMethod() {  
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) extension.

Answer (score 2):

Install one or another (in order of tool complexity):

- [Brace Completer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d) (free)
- [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) (free)
- [ReSharper](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ea4ac039-1b5c-4d11-804e-9bede2e63ecf) (paid)

Answer (score 1):

Use external tools for 2012. But it is a new feature that just got added to Visual Studio 2013.

Details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb386063%28v=vs.120%29.aspx (Look under Nice Code Editor features)